# Can't compile Mex-file with Cplex and Matlab on MAC OSX(Xcode)

Tags: c++, xcode, matlab, mex, cplex

I have a serious problem when I use the cplex optimization studio with matlab on MAC OSX to solve a linear programming problem. I tried to run a mex file so I do

```
mex -I/...../Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex/include -I/....../Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/concert/include -L/......../Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx -lcplex lp_cplex_mex.cpp
```

So in the code above I call `.h header` and the library to use them in `.cpp` file, the first error I get is :

```
...concert/include/ilconcert/ilosys.h:391:10: fatal
error: 'iostream.h' file not found
```

So I go to this line and I change `<iostream.h>` by `<iostream>`, then it can knows the file but in the next compilation I got more than 20 errors again such as:

```
In file included from /.../Desktop/example/lp_cplex_mex.cpp:22:
In file included from...
```

And

```
unknown type name 'ostream'; did you mean 'std::ostream'?
    virtual void print(ILOSTD(ostream)& out) const;
                       ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
                       std::ostream
```

I clarify that:

- I can compile yprime.c and other MEX files that do not use the CPLEX API
- I am using MATLAB 2015a on Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.16
- I am using the GCC package included in XCode 8.2

Also If I try to change in every file for example `ostream` by `std::ostream`, I will not reach anything because is a `Cplex Library` with thousands of lines. On the other hand, I have installed the last edition of cplex and Xcode?!

I wish your advices about this issues because the most solution I found is to change for example `<iostream.h>` by `<iostream>` but as I said it's not a perfect solution because I can change only in my C++ Mex-file not in Cplex!

**EDIT**

Now I'm doing as you said and I added `#define IL_STD`in the head of my `.cpp` compiled file then I get new errors :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"IloNumExpr::IloNumExpr(IloNumExprArg)", referenced from:
  _main in lp_cplex_mex.o
"IloNumArray::IloNumArray(IloEnv, long)", referenced from:
  _main in lp_cplex_mex.o
"IloAddNumVar::~IloAddNumVar()", referenced from:
  _main in lp_cplex_mex.o
"IloObjective::setLinearCoef(IloNumVar, double)", referenced from:
  _main in lp_cplex_mex.o
"IloObjective::IloObjective(IloEnv, double, IloObjective::Sense, char 
const*)", referenced from:
  _main in lp_cplex_mex.o
.......
.......

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

Comment: I don't know the MacOS stuff, but I have had similar errors in the past on other systems. The Windows installation has a file called c_cpp.html that says that the Concert libraries are compiled to use the standard template libraries (i.e. the std:: classes). If building your own project, you should "Add IL_STD to the Preprocessor Definitions field. This choice defines the macro IL_STD which is needed to use the STL". Digging around in the .h files shows that this certainly does something about switching between the original and std:: versions of the io streams headers etc

Comment: I wish if that will resolve my issue, but I have to clarify something, If I use Eclipse for example, I can do  `C/C++ Project Properties" → "Paths and Symbols" → "Symbols`, but I'm on Matlab and Xcode Clang as a compiler, so how to add `IL_STD`?

Comment: Dunno, to be honest. A kind of quick and dirty way that is independent of compilers and IDEs is to put the #define IL_STD  into your own header file and include that as the first include in all your files

Comment: I would to thank you for your help, I guess is work but I got some new errors , can U see my EDIT above...

Comment: Is that a 32 vs 64 bit issue? Or maybe check the libraries are correctly specified?